# Solving Backpropagation

Tags: partial-derivative, machine-learning, chain-rule, neural-networks

[Example to caclulate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufpLC.png)

How would I calculate the gradient here?
I'm stuck for a few days now and any advice would be helpfull :)

With $tanh$ as activation function and MSE as loss function.
$$
\frac{\partial{J(\hat{y},y)}}{\partial{w^{[2]}_{1,2}}} 
= 
\frac{\partial{J(\hat{y},y)}}{\partial{a^3}}
\frac{\partial{a^3}}{\partial z^{[3]}} 
\frac{\partial{z^{[3]}}}{\partial{a^{[2]}_1}}
\frac{\partial{a^{[2]}_1}}{z^{[2]}_1}
\frac{z^{[2]}_1}{w^{[2]}_{1,2}}
$$
Is that correct ?

$m$ is the number of training examples

$n^{[L]}$ is the number of output variables / neurons in the last layer

$a^{[3]}$ is the output/prediction vector $\hat y$
$$
J(\hat{y},y)
= 
J(a^{[3]},y)
=
\frac{1}{m}
\sum_{i=1}^{m}
  \frac{1}{n^{[L]}}
  \sum_{j=1}^{n^{[L]}}
   (a^{[3]}_j-y^{[3]}_j)^2
$$

$$
\frac
 {\partial J(a^{[3]},y)}
 {\partial {a^{[3]}}}
=
??
$$

Answer (score 1):

You got it almost right. but you missed a little point. a and z are not numbers or variables. they are matrices. so when computing the partial derivative, you should compute it as a vector. so we have:

$$
\frac{\partial J(a^{[3]}, y)}{\partial a^{[3]}} = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\partial J(a^{[3]}, y)}{\partial a_1^{[3]}} &
   \frac{\partial J(a^{[3]}, y)}{\partial a_2^{[3]}} & 
   \frac{\partial J(a^{[3]}, y)}{\partial a_3^{[3]}}
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

and we can compute:

$$
 \begin{align}
   \frac{\partial J(a^{[3]}, y)}{\partial a_k^{[3]}} &= 
   \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n^{[L]}}
   2(a_k^{[3]} - y_k^{[3]})\\
   &= 
   \frac{2}{m n^{[L]}} \sum_{i=1}^{m}
   (a_k^{[3]} - y_k^{[3]})
 \end{align}
$$